Is it possible to update a kotlin notebook cell from another thread?
For my purposes, it would be very interesting to have some code run in the background,  but still send status updates to an output cell. E.g.:
thread {
    val numIters = 10
    repeat(numIters) { step ->
        Thread.sleep(1.seconds.toJavaDuration())
        println("Important task: ${step + 1} / $numIters")
    }
}

If I then execute other code in another cell, the first cell does not show the desired output (the output is displayed at the next cell executed).
How can I achieve this goal? I already tried to use notebook.display and notebook.update_display, but did not succeed.
Thank you!
